# How to render an object tree with paging?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I’ll render an object graph on a page looking like this:

- Category 1

  - Module 1

    - Product 1
    - Product 2
    - Product 3
  - Module 2

    - Product 4
- Category 2

  - ...

The Category has an IList<Module> and the Module contains an IList<Product>
Now I need to implement paging on this structure but the problem is that I can’t do Category.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize) because this will only work on the Category object not the whole object tree.  In other words I like to render out when the sum of Categories, Modules and Products is equal to the PageSize

/erik

Comment: Don't do it! Paging trees like this would make for dreadful usability - page 2 could end up starting halfway down a hierarchy with a bunch of orphaned modules and product links...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I want to note that this will result in a terrible UI because the second page will show a random slice of the tree. You could first get all tuples { Module, CountOfProducts } from the database (create an indexed view so performance will be excellent). Then you can walk that tree and skip ahead as far as necessary. The framework does not have the necessary components builtin but maybe TakeWhile will help. This question unfortunately has only either very long or incomplete (like mine) answers. Hope to have set you ontrack.

Answer (score 0):

create something like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Category
    {
        public IList<Module> Modules {get; private set;}

        public IEnumerable<Module> AggregatedModules
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (var p in Modules)
                {
                    yield return p;
                }
            }
        }
        public IEnumerable<Product> AggregatedProducts
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (var m in Modules)
                {
                    foreach (var p in m.Products)
                    {
                        yield return p;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class Module
    {
        public IList<Product> Products {get; private set;}

        public IEnumerable<Product> AggregatedProducts
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (var p in Products)
                {
                    yield return p;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Product
    {
    }

    class Test
    {
        public void Test1()
        {
            Category c = new Category();

            c.AggregatedProducts.Take(4).Skip(12);

            IList<Category> cs = new List<Category>();

            cs.EnumerablePropertyUnion(cat => cat.AggregatedProducts);

        }
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T2> EnumerablePropertyUnion<T,T2>(
        this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T2>> propertyEnumerator
        )
    {
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            foreach (var subitem in propertyEnumerator(item))
            {
                yield return subitem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, but I cant convert IEnumreble<Product> to yield type Product. Should I cast this to Product?

Comment: I've updated the code. There was actually a mistake in the code

Comment: Great. But I wonder how I can use it when I have a list of Categories. Like: categoryList.AggregateProducts.Take(2).Skip(12);

Comment: code update. It starts to be messy. Maybe you can expose what you are trying to achieve (in a higher level than code level).

Comment: Thanx, Sure I got an IList<Category> containing an IList<Module> that contains an IList<Product>. I render out this object graph in the GUI using a foreach. But I need paging so that the sum of Categories, Modules and Products always is the same for every page. 
Let’s say that I output on each page should be ten items. Page 1 can then have 3 categories, 4 modules and 3 products. Page two may contain 1 category, 2 modules and 7 products and so on.

Comment: but how do you deal the page 2, when the first item is a product ? The parent category may be on the previous page

Comment: Yes, that's a problem. Maybe we have to rerender that category on page two, but I think that would be confusing for the users. Or we have to finish all the items of one category so the next page always starts with a new category, but then the size of the output table will differ from page to page. 
Hmm,  that’s tricky. The approach I’m using now is that every page renders two categories. But some categories may just contain one product and others can contain twenty. So I need some kind of logic to deal with this. Any thoughts?

Comment: what is your render technology ? web ? winform ?sl ?

Comment: Web and I'm using a kind of mvc style rendering <% foreach(var category in Categories) { %>. I do not use databindings